# Calling an application by the bundle signature using JXA (macOS)

Tags: macos, javascript-automation, bundle-identifier, cfbundleidentifier

When calling an application using JXA (JavaScript for automation), you can refer to the app by the bundle name or by the identifier, just like in AppleScript:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
tell application id "com.apple.TextEdit" to activate
```

are equivalent to

```
Application('TextEdit').activate();
Application('com.apple.TextEdit').activate();
```

But in AppleScript one can also call an app by the bundle signature, which is often version-invariant and stable over time:

```
tell application id "ttxt" to activate
```

What is the JXA equivalent of this latter call? How can one create version-independent JXA scripts?

Comment: according to the documentation, you should be able to reference by just using the bundleID - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW6

Comment: Did you ever quickly tried `Application('com.apple.TextEdit').activate();`?  However the *FourCharCode* identifier seems to be exclusively related to AppleScript.

Comment: @MikeDiglio and vadian are right. But the main issue I have (having a version-independent handle) does not get resolved using your solution. I assumed calling the identifier and the signature would follow the same syntax under JXA, but that is not the case. I edited the question to reflect the issue.

Comment: Which application uses different bundle identifiers for different versions?

Comment: @vadian Turns out some of my most beloved and most heavily scripted apps: com.devon-technologies.think3, com.phaseone.captureone12, com.stata.stata16, com.flexibits.fantastical2.mac.